# sequelize transactions in expressjs not executing

Tags: node.js, express, transactions, sequelize.js

Trying to figure out the right way to use Sequelize transactions in expressjs. 
The following code finds a post by id increments the reply count in the post table, updates the post and then creates a reply in the reply table. Trying to call the code in a controller action and it does not work. The internal promises are not being hit. Any suggestions on the right way to use the transactions in Sequelize?

```
Sequelize.transaction(function (t) {  
db.Post.find({where:{id: postId}}, {transaction:t}).then(function(post)
{
  var count = post.reply + 1; 
  post.update({replyCount:count},{transaction:t});
  db.Reply.create(replyData, {transaction:t}).then(function(newcomment, created){      
          res.json(newcomment);

      });     
});
  }).then(function (result) {
// Transaction has been committed
// result is whatever the result of the promise chain returned to the transaction callback 
 }).catch(function (err) {
// Transaction has been rolled back
// err is whatever rejected the promise chain returned to the transaction 
});        
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sequelize.transaction(function (t) {  
 return db.Post.find({where:{id: postId}}, {transaction:t}).then(function(post)
{
  var count = post.reply + 1; 
  return post.update({replyCount:count},{transaction:t})
         .success(result =>
              // i guess you want to use result in here to create replyData
              return db.Reply.create(replyData, {transaction:t})

                     .then(function(newcomment, created){      
                           return res.json(newcomment);

                      }); 
         );

});
```

Comment: This answer does address "the right way to use Sequelize transactions". It does not address the fact that the initial .find() query does not alter the database and thus has no value in being in the transaction. Please see the ES6 solution below the uses a try/catch, awaits and the auto transaction functionality to address the question.

Answer (score 0):

There's no value in the initial .find() being in the transaction. There's nothing to undo in the case of a rollback. Only writes or updates need to be rolled back in a transaction. The try/catch will deal with any of the queries failing and a rollback will be automatically triggered for the transaction items.

Consider this more modern ES6 solution:

```
try {

  const result = await sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {

    // no need to include this in the transaction, it only reads (find)
    const post = await db.Post.find({where:{id: postId}});

    const count = post.reply + 1;
    const updateResult = await post.update({
      replyCount: count
    }, { transaction: t });

    // i guess you want to use result in here to create replyData
    const createResult = await db.Reply.create({
      replyData,
    }, { transaction:t });

    return res.json(newcomment);
  });

} catch (error) {

  // If the execution reaches this line, an error occurred.
  // The transaction has already been rolled back automatically by Sequelize!

}
```

Reference:
  - https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html#managed-transactions